# Seek to line number in text file using C

Tags: c, fseek

I have an ASCII binary file which looks something like:

```
00010110001001000110011001000111
01011000011100001010100001001000
11110001011010000010010101111010
00000000000000000000000000000000
01011010101000010001010101110000
```

Each line has 32 characters (so it is of length 33 with `\n`). I am trying to seek my file pointer to the line that comes right after the `0x0` line (the 4th line in the above example).

What I did was as follows. First, I counted how many lines are in the file. So `5` in this case. I also kept an index at the line which holds the `0x0` line. So `4` in this case. I multiplied `4` by `33` which returns which character the first number after the `0x0` is (I have to add a 1 since this actually returns the `\n` at the end of the `0x0` line.

After that, I just used `fseek`. However, it is not working. What is wrong here? Here is my code:

```
int bytes = 33 * c;
fseek(fp, bytes+1, SEEK_SET);
char test[34];
printf("HERE: '%s'", fgets(test, 34, fp));
```

Thanks!

Comment: The line number which holds the line of zeros is line 3, not line 4.

Comment: Anytime you say "it's not working" or "I get an error", you need to explain **exactly** what those phrases mean. Exactly *how* is it "not working"? If it's an error, what is the **exact** error message? Please remember that we can't see your screen from here, and the only thing we have to go on is what you type in your question. If you want help solving a problem, you have to be clear on what the problem is that you're actually trying to solve. In other words, help us to help you. :)

Comment: @Russel, that depends on whether you consider the line at the top to be the first or the zeroth :-)

Comment: The first byte of the first line is at file offset 0. If your algorithm doesn't give you an offset of zero for the first line, it's broken.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz How would I print the offset of the first line?

Comment: @Nayefc: The offset of the first line is zero (since it starts at the first byte of the file, offset zero). Your algorithm is '33*c + 1'. That gives 34 for the offset of the first line if '1' is the first line or 1 for the offset of the first line if '0' is the first line. Either way, it's wrong.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz it worked though. See below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you *don't* have to add one at all. The offset of the first character in the file is 0.

The offset if the first character on the second line is 33 (assuming your line-ending really *is* a newline, not a CR/LF combo).

First character on third line is at offset 66.

So your code should actually be:

```
int bytes = 33 * c;
fseek (fp, bytes, SEEK_SET);  // no "+1" here.
char test[34];
printf ("HERE: '%s'", fgets(test, 34, fp));
```

---

Here's a transcript showing that in action:

```
pax$ cat qq.in
00010110001001000110011001000111
01011000011100001010100001001000
11110001011010000010010101111010
00000000000000000000000000000000
11110000111100001111000011110000

pax$ cat qq.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    char test[34];
    int c = 4;
    FILE *fp = fopen ("qq.in", "r");

    int bytes = 33 * c;
    fseek (fp, bytes, SEEK_SET);
    printf("HERE: %s", fgets(test, 34, fp));

    fclose (fp);
    return 0;
}

pax$ gcc -o qq qq.c ; ./qq
HERE: 11110000111100001111000011110000
```

---

Try that code in your environment and see what happens. If you don't get the right data then there's a mismatch between your code and your input file of some sort.

You haven't specified what platform you're on so it *may* be that you actually have `\r\n` at the end of the lines rather than just `\n`. You may also be opening it in the wrong mode (though that usually only matters on Windows).

Doing a dump on the file to validate its contents is a good idea. For example, in a UNIXy system:

```
pax$ od -xcb qq.in

0000000    3030    3130    3130    3031    3030    3031    3130    3030
          0   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0
        060 060 060 061 060 061 061 060 060 060 061 060 060 061 060 060
0000020    3130    3031    3130    3031    3130    3030    3130    3131
          0   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1
        060 061 061 060 060 061 061 060 060 061 060 060 060 061 061 061
0000040    300a    3031    3131    3030    3030    3131    3031    3030
         \n   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0
        012 060 061 060 061 061 060 060 060 060 061 061 061 060 060 060
:
<< Unnecessary Detail Removed >>
:
0000240    3030    3030    000a
          0   0   0   0  \n
        060 060 060 060 012
0000245
```

In addition, you may want to print out the values of `c` and `bytes` before using them. The `fgets` function will only return NULL if there's an error or you reach EOF before any data is read.

So, if you're getting NULL as the return value, either you've seeked beyond the end of the file (likely) or you've encountered an error (somewhat less likely but not impossible).

Comment: @Nayefc: then your input file is not what you think.

Comment: It is. It is txt file that matches exactly what you have. Do you have an extra line at the end? I also reseted my file pointer using `fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET)` just incase.

Comment: @Nayefc: first things first. Type in my `qq.in` and `qq.c` files, compile them and run. This will tell you if your environment is broken somehow. It's possible but I doubt it. Next step, print out the values of `c` and `bytes` and the `od` of your input file. Then create a complete, compilable program as small as possible that still exhibits this errant behaviour. Then we can work on that.

Comment: I am running Mac, so \r doesn't exist I believe.

Comment: Well, it _exists,_ but it's not used in text files in modern MacOS. I'm assuming you're not running a pre-OSX version where the line ending was `\r` on its own (from memeory). But that's an aside, you need to follow the steps outlined above.

Comment: Found the problem. I have the following while loop before to calculate `c`. It is as follows: `while (fgets(line, MAX_LENGTH+2, fp) != NULL) { c++; }`  Once I add this, it doesn't work. When I remove it, then it works and the next line prints. I used `rewind` and it would still print `(null)`.

Comment: Well, that would have set `c` to the number of lines in the file so that, when you seek to `c*33`, you're _after_ the last line. Hence EOF and `fgets` returning NULL.

Comment: Can't believe I made this mistake. Stupid. Thanks!